# Responsive hover drop down 100% width menu

Tags: html, css

So I'm working on a school project that we have to make responsive, so I figured I'd add a burger menu icon when the width of the site reaches 768px or below. I want a 100% width submenu to appear when you hover over the burger menu icon, but when I hover over the image the image jumps to the next row and if you keep the width at around 768px you can see that the submenu isn't actually 100%.

I've been messing around with it so much that I don't even know what I'm doing anymore and which parts of the code I need/don't need.

`enter code here`

I copy pasted the entire HTML/CSS into this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXWERw

You have to put the website at 768px width to test it.

I would very much appreciate some help here as I'm completely lost at this point!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find your mistake, I would organize the code differently in some ways.

1. **Mobile first:** If you build a responsive website, start with the mobile part and then resize your browser window until your website doesn't look nice anymore and insert a media query.
2. **Don't duplicate code:** Your menu is two times in your HTML, with smart css you should never be forced to do so (→ easy maintaining)
3. **Line-breaking nav:** Making the navbar two lines doesn't look that nice in most cases, better try to avoid this

Here's my try: http://jsfiddle.net/okpdk4n5/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mobile-show-nav').click(function() {
        $('.nav-items').toggleClass('visible');
    });
});
```

```css
/* --> reset */
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

body {
    font: 400 12pt sans-serif;
}

nav, div, ul, li, img {
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul, li {
    list-style: none;
}
/* <-- reset */

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background: #14549c;
    color: #fff;
}

.nav-logo {
    float:left;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
}
.nav-icon {
    float: right;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav-icon img {
    width: 100%;
}

.nav-items {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    transition: height .35s;
}

.nav-items.visible {
    height:auto;
}

.nav-items li {
    width: 100%;
    height:50px;
    line-height:50px;
    background: #555;
    padding: 0 15px;
    border-bottom:solid 1px #666;
}

@media(min-width: 800px) {
.mobile-show-nav {
    display: none;
}
.nav-items-container {
    float:left;
    width: calc( 100% - 210px );
    height:60px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.nav-items {
    display:table;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.nav-items li {
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;
    background:none;
    border:none;
    line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <div class="nav-logo">Maskinfabrikken</div>
    <div class="nav-icon mobile-show-nav"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/food-and-drink-part-2/512/94-512.png"></div>
    <div class="nav-icon"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/web/512/Shopping_Cart-512.png">
    </div>
    <div class="nav-items-container">
        <ul class="nav-items">
            <li>Produkter</li>
            <li>Arrangementer</li>
            <li>Kontakt</li>
            <li>Downloads</li>
            <li>Om os</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fugaz+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <nav>
              <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.php">Maskinfabrikken</a>
              </div>

              <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw96Z.png" width="40" height="auto" />
              <ul>
                <li><a href="products.php">Produkter</a></li>
                <li><a href="events.php">Arrangementer</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Kontakt</a></li>
                <li><a href="downloads.php">Downloads</a></li>
                <li><a href="aboutus.php">Om os</a></li>
                <li><a href="shoppingcart.php">Indkøbskurv</a></li>
              </ul>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </nav>
        </header>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS (Minified):

```
body,html{margin:0;padding:0;background-color:#e7e7e7;font-family:Helvetica}.container{width:100%;max-width:1080px;min-height:500px;margin:0 auto;background-color:#fff}nav{background-color:#14549c;padding:10px 20px}.logo>a{font-family:"Fugaz One";font-size:2.15em}nav .logo{float:left}.clearfix::after{content:"";clear:both;display:table}nav a{color:#fff;text-decoration:none}nav ul{float:right;list-style:none;display:-webkit-inline-box;display:inline-flex}nav li{padding:0 20px}nav img{display:none}nav li:first-child{padding-left:0}nav li:last-child{padding-right:0}@media all and (max-width:1035px){nav,nav ul{text-align:center;padding:0}nav{padding-top:10px}nav ul{margin-bottom:0;padding:0;width:100%;display:none;margin-top:0}nav img,nav img:hover+ul,nav ul:hover{display:block}nav .logo,nav ul{float:none}nav img{margin:0 auto -5px}nav li{padding:10px 0;background-color:red}}
```

You can find the source and working example at [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgMQEX)

**Things you should consider**

- The media query activates at 1035px, you wanted 768px. I determined that 1035px was better because your menu items are too large.
- I rewrote the HTML because you had two menus. You only really need one and the rest should be styled for either Desktop, Tablet and Mobile using media queries or a CSS mobile framework.
- I don't have your resources (images) so I removed them from my example because it just showed a broken image link.